# inline editing in textblock of a wpf application?

Tags: wpf

I am  working on a wpf application and i have to implement inline editing in text box and update them in database as well. Please give me the right way of doing this, Thanks.

Comment: Hi Anu, are you using a Grid to present your data?

Comment: yes i have to do it in both datagrid and Textblock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you do it in WPF is - Binding. Have a read on it:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx